# Is there a way to optimize reading of large JSON files in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, performance, optimization

Is there a way to optimize the following code?
I am reading a large json file from a bucket, and serving the data to the client based on the coordinates of the user, and returning results within a specified distance.

I want to be able to serve all the data at once, thus removing the need for a distance to query within.

```
if (!$restrictions) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Requested data was not found'
        ], BaseResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    $json = json_decode($restrictions, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    if (isset($validFields['latitude'], $validFields['longitude'])) {
        $distanceLimit = $validFields['distance'] ?? 1;
        foreach ($json['features'] as $key => $feature) {
            foreach ($feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0] as $coords) {
                $distance = $this->calculateDistance(
                    [
                        'latitude' => $validFields['latitude'],
                        'longitude' => $validFields['longitude']
                    ],
                    [
                        'longitude' => $coords[0],
                        'latitude' => $coords[1]
                    ]
                );
                if ($distance > $distanceLimit) {
                    unset($json['features'][$key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //Reindexing the features
        $json['features'] = array_values($json['features']);
        $json['totalFeatures'] = count($json['features']);
    }
    return response()->json($json, BaseResponse::HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How does this link to AWS? If it is not a contributing factor to the problem, please remove the tag.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It was a typo - Apologies.